# scroll through a json api and find the values true or false flutter

Tags: json, api, flutter, dart

I'm trying to get a flutter api result. The fact is that the tutorial I was following shows how to receive a JSON list and how to analyze it, but I need to know how to receive a certain data from the API and make a condition to handle this data, I need to know if I find the snippet ( ignition: true) the car's trip is active, the car is moving if (ignition: false) the car has reached the end of the trip, it's stopped, I even know the logic I need to do but I don't know how to analyze it from JSON. Below is the code I'm working on, I'm stuck.

As soon as I'm reading the data:

```
class DetailPage extends StatelessWidget {
  final Car user;
  var travels = [];

  DetailPage(this.user);

  Future<List<Position>> _getCarros() async {
    var data = await http.get(
        "http://www15.itrack.com.br/vehicles/${user.id}/positions");

    var jsonData = json.decode(data.body);

    List<Position> carros = [];

    for (var u in jsonData) {
      Position carro = Position(
          u["id"],
          u["vehicleId"],
          u["datetime"],
          u["latitude"],
          u["longitude"],
          u["address"],
          u["ignition"],
          u["hodometro"]);

      carros.add(carro);
    }
    print(carros.length);
    return carros;
  }

 

     @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(user.name),
      ),
      body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: _getCarros(),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int id) {
                  return Card(
                    child: ListTile(
                      title: Text(snapshot.data[id].ignition.toString()),
                      subtitle: Text(snapshot.data[id].hodometro.toString()),
                    ),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),
    );

And that was the function I did in javascript but I don't know how to do it in dart (I'm new to flutter)

var positionInicial = null
var travels = []
for(var i =0; i < positions.size; i++){
  if(positionInicial == null && positions[i].ignition == true){
    positionInicial = positions[i]
  }
  if(positionInicial != null && positions[i].ignition == false){
   travels.push(trave{initial: positionInital.id, final: positions[i].id})
    positionInicial = null
  }
}
```

This is the API for the trips of a given vehicle in this case with id = 1.

```
    {
    "id": 1,
    "vehicleId": 1,
    "datetime": 1612455145422,
    "latitude": -19.915,
    "longitude": -43.945,
    "address": "Rua V01, P01 - Centro",
    "ignition": true,
    "hodometro": 120000
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "vehicleId": 1,
    "datetime": 1612455205422,
    "latitude": -19.915,
    "longitude": -43.945,
    "address": "Rua V01, P02 - Centro",
    "ignition": true,
    "hodometro": 120100
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "vehicleId": 1,
    "datetime": 1612455265422,
    "latitude": -19.915,
    "longitude": -43.945,
    "address": "Rua V01, P03 - Centro",
    "ignition": false,
    "hodometro": 120200
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "vehicleId": 1,
    "datetime": 1612455325422,
    "latitude": -19.915,
    "longitude": -43.945,
    "address": "Rua V01, P04 - Centro",
    "ignition": false,
    "hodometro": 120300
},
{
    "id": 5,
    "vehicleId": 1,
    "datetime": 1612455385422,
    "latitude": -19.915,
    "longitude": -43.945,
    "address": "Rua V01, P05 - Centro",
    "ignition": true,
    "hodometro": 120400
},
{
    "id": 6,
    "vehicleId": 1,
    "datetime": 1612455445422,
    "latitude": -19.915,
    "longitude": -43.945,
    "address": "Rua V01, P06 - Centro",
    "ignition": false,
    "hodometro": 120500
},
{
    "id": 7,
    "vehicleId": 1,
    "datetime": 1612455505422,
    "latitude": -19.915,
    "longitude": -43.945,
    "address": "Rua V01, P07 - Centro",
    "ignition": true,
    "hodometro": 120600
}
```

Result:

- Position1: ignition - on

  - Position2: ignition - on
  - Position3: ignition - off
  - Position4: ignition - off
  - Position5: ignition - on
  - Position6: ignition - off
  - Position7: ignition - on

Final:

- Travel1: Position1 à Position3
- Travel2: Position5 à Position6
- Travel3: Position7

Answer (score 0):

**CODE UPDATED (02-03-2021)**

NetService

```
class NetService {
  static Future<T> getJson<T>(String url) {
    return http.get(Uri.parse(url))
      .then((response) {
        if (response.statusCode == 200) {
          return jsonDecode(response.body) as T;
        }
        print('Status Code : ${response.statusCode}...');
        return null;
      })
      .catchError((err) => print(err));
  }
}
```

Main

```
import 'dart:io';

import 'package:_samples2/networking.dart';

class Travel {
  static const baseUrl = 'http://www15.itrack.com.br/recruitmentpositionapi/vehicles';
  var data = [];
  
  void fetchPositions() async {
    var id = 1;
    var flag = true;
    print('Start fetching...');

    await Future.doWhile(() async {
      await NetService
        .getJson<List>('$baseUrl/$id/positions')
        .then((response) {
          response != null && response.isNotEmpty
            ? data.addAll(response)
            : flag = false;
        })
        .whenComplete(() {
          print('Fetching done for ID $id...');
          id++;
        });
      return flag;
    });

    print('Job done!\n');
  }

  void listPositions() {
    data.forEach((m) => print('Position ${m['id']} : ignition - ${m['ignition'] ? 'on' : 'off'}'));
    print('');
  }

  void listTravels() {
    var points = data.map((m) => [m['id'], m['ignition']]).toList();
    var journeys = <List<int>>[];

    void calculateJourney([int from = 0]) {
      if (from != null  && from >= 0) {
        int start, stop;
        start = points.indexWhere((e) => e[1], from);
        if (start >= 0) stop = points.indexWhere((e) => !e[1], start);
        journeys.add([start, stop]);
        calculateJourney(stop);
      }
    }
    calculateJourney();
    for (var i = 0; i < journeys.length; i++) {
      stdout.write('Travel ${i+1} : Position ${points[journeys[i][0]][0]}');
      journeys[i][1] >= 0
        ? print(' to Position ${points[journeys[i][1]][0]}')
        : print('');
    }
  }
}

void main(List<String> args) async {
  var travel = Travel();
  await travel.fetchPositions();
  travel
    ..listPositions()
    ..listTravels();
}
```

Result:

```
Start fetching...
Fetching done for ID 1...
Fetching done for ID 2...
Fetching done for ID 3...
Fetching done for ID 4...
Fetching done for ID 5...
Job done!

Position 1 : ignition - on
Position 2 : ignition - on
Position 3 : ignition - off
Position 4 : ignition - off
Position 5 : ignition - on
Position 6 : ignition - off
Position 7 : ignition - on
Position 8 : ignition - off
Position 9 : ignition - on
Position 10 : ignition - on
Position 11 : ignition - on
Position 12 : ignition - on
Position 13 : ignition - off
Position 14 : ignition - on
Position 15 : ignition - on
Position 16 : ignition - on
Position 17 : ignition - off
Position 18 : ignition - off
Position 19 : ignition - off
Position 20 : ignition - off
Position 21 : ignition - off
Position 22 : ignition - on
Position 23 : ignition - on
Position 24 : ignition - on
Position 25 : ignition - on

Travel 1 : Position 1 to Position 3
Travel 2 : Position 5 to Position 6
Travel 3 : Position 7 to Position 8
Travel 4 : Position 9 to Position 13
Travel 5 : Position 14 to Position 17
Travel 6 : Position 22
```

Comment: void fetchPositions() => data = jsonDecode(positions);

Comment: thanks for the answer but I'm not able to implement this with error in positions

Comment: Which error? Could you explain it in more detail? `void fetchPositions() => data = jsonDecode(positions);` is simulating to fetch data from API because I don't know your real URL, I get your sample data only.

Comment: that's what i call the url
var data = await http.get (
         "http://www15.itrack.com.br/vehicles/${user.id}/positions");

     var jsonData = json.decode (data.body);

Comment: And what is the value for `user.id`?

Comment: this user_id is because I have a screen where I list all the cars I search for from the first url, which has the name of the car, the make, the model, so far so good, when I click on a car it goes to another screen with this url http://www15.itrack.com.br/recruitmentpositionapi/vehicles/1/positions where user_id is the id of each car, in this case the car id = 1, it has several trips, starting with (ignition = true) to (ignition = false)

Comment: OK, I'll update my code to fetch data from this API, but I must note this URL is different from the one you mentioned above `http://www15.itrack.com.br/vehicles/${user.id}/positions`. Now I need a confirmation from you, Is this the error you were referring to? If not, explain it in more detail please.

Comment: I'm sorry vdd I put the wrong url in my question, that's right the error would be in the positions of this function void fetchPositions () => data = jsonDecode (positions), which in my case would be my url